# Field not inserting or updating , int type in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am working on magento platform.I face a problem regarding values insertion to specific field: My query run perfect but one specific column not working for any query.I try my best but didn't find why .When i change the column type from int to varchar type it works.This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `followupemails_emaillogs` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followupemails_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.
```

the "followupemails_id" column not working in insert and update query.This is one update query where record exist that id(29). `UPDATE followupemails_emaillogs SET followupemails_id=5 WHERE id =29`.
This is insertion query `INSERT INTO followupemails_emaillogs SET followupemails_id=4, schedule_time='2013-10-23 08:10:00', email_status='pending', client_name='ayaz ali'`.this works fine on fiddle but not on my sqlyog ? what could be the issue.At last i find query that work perfect

`.INSERT INTO followupemails_emaillogs (followupemails_id,schedule_time,email_status,client_name,client_email) VALUES (26,'2013-10-23 08:10:00','pending','ayaz ali','mamhmood@yahoo.com');`
Can anyone tell me why set query not working but second query works perfect.so that i can accept his answer.Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Cfreak I add simple update query to my question.

Comment: As far as I can see, [it works well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4171e/1).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I also write down my insertion query that works fine on you demo example but didn't work on my sqlyog.what can cause be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole query is ok

```
CREATE TABLE `followupemails_emaillogs` (
`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followupemails_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.
```

but at the last there is dot which is actually error so remove the dot and create the table

```
latin1.
```

so remove the dot sign and not null in id filed use this line by default fields are null so don't use default null

```
id int (8) AUTO_INCREMENT

CREATE TABLE `followupemails_emaillogs` (
`id` int (8) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_status` varchar(100),
  `client_name` varchar(250),
  `client_email` varchar(250),
  `followupemails_id` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: there is no issue in table query dear.

Comment: copy your update query into sql yog and execute there if record is updating thats mean there isn't issue in query.

Comment: I've executed the query in my sql yog it inserted the record

Comment: yes i know the query working on any other system except my one.I want to figure out why its not working for me.

Comment: check my question for edits.and dear don't use yaar in communication.

Comment: sorry for yaar and again the data inserted

Comment: can you tell me the version of mysql database?

Comment: Its done dear leave it.I figure out my problem.thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't understand! what was the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

To Create,

```
CREATE TABLE followupemails_emaillogs (
  id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  schedule_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  sent_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  email_status varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  client_name varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  client_email varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  followupemails_i int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE (id)
)
```

To Insert,

```
INSERT INTO followupemails_emaillogs (schedule_time,sent_time,email_status,client_name,client_email,followupemails_i) 
VALUES 
('2012-05-05','2012-05-06',"sent","sagar","sagar@xxxx.com",2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> don't need *(11)* in the sql query for int operator , This get for length of the  nvarchar,varchar datatype column only not a int datatype,So change and write **`int`** instead of  *`int(11)`* and  *`int(8)`*

Try this query instead of your query

```
CREATE TABLE `followupemails_emaillogs` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schedule_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followupemails_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.
```

Comment: i am using sql yog for table creation so when enter length for table it create table in above structure.

Comment: `INT(11)` is perfectly valid syntax in MySQL.

Comment: when i remove the length it takes 11 by default for the int.